# Python how to pass/read in arguments through the command line without using external modules on Linux

Tags: python, linux, arguments, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to run a python script in Linux and I'd like to pass in arguments that I can use in the program. Everywhere I look people are importing sys or argparse but I'm trying to do this without external modules. So for example say I want to do:

```
python3 myScript.py -number 1 -word "test"
```

Then I could just use the number and word variables in my program. Is this possible?

Comment: `argparse` and `sys` are base libraries (not external)

Comment: You can't do it without importing `sys` so you can use `sys.argv`.